# Getting oci_execute(): ORA-01843: not a valid month invalid in php while inserting record?

Tags: php, oracle

I am getting oci_execute(): ORA-01843: not a valid month invalid. Why it is giving it?

```
INSERT INTO DETAIL (PPD_ID, PPD_ID,PPD_ENTRY_DATE, PPD_IGM_ID, PPD_DFM_ID, PPD_DRM_ID, PPD_HEIGHT, PPD_UOM_ID, PPD_FTM_ID, PPD_FRQ_ID, PPD_START_DATE_TIME, PPD_END_DATE_TIME, PPD_STATUS, PPD_STM_ID) 
VALUES ('WS00318229',2440900,'29-12-2015',350,1,1,50,46,1,1,'29-12-2015','29-12-2015','PRESCRIBED',6)
```

When i am using the above query from php to insert record in to oracle database it is giving following error.

```
oci_execute(): ORA-01843: not a valid month invalid
```

But when i use the following query it is not giving any error and it is inserting record.How to solve this? This error was already is there but i am not clear about the answers.Any ideas why it is like this.

```
INSERT INTO DETAIL (PPD_ID, PPD_ID,PPD_ENTRY_DATE, PPD_IGM_ID, PPD_DFM_ID, PPD_DRM_ID, PPD_HEIGHT, PPD_UOM_ID, PPD_FTM_ID, PPD_FRQ_ID, PPD_START_DATE_TIME, PPD_END_DATE_TIME, PPD_STATUS, PPD_STM_ID) 
VALUES ('WS00318229',2440900,'29-DEC-2015',350,1,1,50,46,1,1,'29-DEC-2015','29-DEC-2015','PRESCRIBED',6)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are inserting strings into `DATE` columns. When you do that, oracle performs implicit conversion based on your [NLS](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A87860_01/doc/server.817/a76966/preface.htm) settings, specifically, `nls_date_format`. Evidently when you connect from php script and from some client you use (SQL*Plus, SQL Developer, what have you), your NLS settings differ.

You can check session parameters using following query.

```
SELECT * FROM nls_session_parameters;
```

For date presented in format `'29-DEC-2015'` `nls_date_format` should be `'DD-MON-YYYY'`. If it has some other value, you can change it using following query.

```
alter session set nls_date_format='DD-MON-YYYY'
```

Or you can explicitly convert string to date using `TO_DATE` function and passing format as second parameter, but this will require your application code to be consistent in using only specified date format.

```
TO_DATE('29-DEC-2015', 'DD-MON-YYYY')
```

Comment: But in my case client sends data in 29-12-2015 but php to oracle is accepting 29-DEC-2015. Is there a way that oracle accepts in this 29-12-2015 format?@that young man

Comment: Oracle accepts a lot of different formats, you just need to specify, which one you want it to apply. When you create connection, your application initializes NLS session parameters. You can then change them using `alter session set nls_date_format='DD-MM-YYYY'` so that implicit conversion succeds getting  `'29-12-2015'`.